# Why doesn't Apache start in MAMP?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, httpd, mamp

I have installed `MAMP` on `OSX` and while `MySQL` is running, `Apache` doesn't start. Here are some screen shots I have to describe the situation. Also when I start the server (or before that) httpd is not found in activity monitor. 
[image]

Here's the screen shot showing web sharing is off:
[image]

And here's the screen shot showing that what are the selected ports (I have tried 8888 for Apache but it's the same exact result):
[image]

Comment: Check the Apache log file

Comment: check that your suggested port for Apache is not using by another program . commands like netstat on windows may help you

Answer (score 2):

Go to your MAMP folder in Applications. Go to bin -> apache2 -> bin:

Then rename the file from "envvars" to "_envvars".

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro

Answer (score 1):

It may be tied to your user name.  If you haven't already, try logging in on your MAC as user admin ( if the account still exists ).  It seems to be something to do with the spaces in the user name.  Works for me.  Although I would rather log in as me I am not sure of the implications of editing my username to exclude spaces.

Andy